# How to apply 2 different kinds of styles to a single Android control?

Tags: android

Say I have this:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyEditText">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    ........
```

And this (not in a file yet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />


</shape>
```

And an EditText.

- In which file should I put the 2nd piece of the code?
- How can I apply these 2 styles to a single EditBox?

Comment: you can do it in this way:  style="@style/MyEditText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The properties that are defined a style xml file and applied to a view ( by setting `style="@style/my_custom_style"` can be overridden.

For example, if in the **style** file I have defined a background, I can re-assign that property in the xml layout of that view again, or even programmatically.

Consequently, if for the example view, I set both `style="@style/my_custom_style"` (including background property with the value of **drawable_one**) and `android:background="@drawable/**drawable_two**"`, then **eventually the drawable_two will take effect**.

---

In the **style.xml** file add the background item

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/your_drawable_xml</item>
```

And for its value (**your_drawable_xml)**, use the second drawable xml.

Now you can apply both in the layout declaration of EditText:

```
style="@style/MyEditText"
```

Comment: how will "your_drawable_xml" know that it has to be applied to EditBox? What if I wanted to apply it to only a single EditBox and not all?

Comment: If you set a property in a style file and apply it to a view, you can override it, by assigning your desired value to it, either in the layout or programmatically

Comment: what property? how apply?